# TinyMCE plugin get reference to the original textarea

Tags: jquery, tinymce

#### The Setup

Many TinyMCE editors, displayed in jQuery tabs, each editor is for a specific language.

#### The problem

I need a plugin with a button, that when pressed will retrieve some html (via ajax) based on the language of the textbox. The best ideea I could come up with is to put am attribute on the textarea containing the language and then in the plugin, get the value of the attribute and based on that make the ajax request to the right url.

#### The question

How do I get a reference to the original textarea from inside the TinyMCE plugin.

Any info/reference is welcomed... I find the TinyMCE API page really hard to follow.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try

```
tinyMCE.get(editorId).getElement();
```

This will return the textarea element that got replaced by TinyMCE - see the [docs](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3%3amethod.tinymce.Editor.getElement).

For your specific needs, if you need to target a certain editor with your externally fetched data, simply loop through all editor instances and select the right one by id or name attribute.

```
for (editorId in tinyMCE.editors) {
  var orig_element = $(tinyMCE.get(editorId).getElement());
  var name = orig_element.attr('name');
  if (name === 'my_field_name') {
    // do your stuff here
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks it worked brilliantly. Sometime you just need another pair of eyes.